How can I change the name of the database in a ddev project?
Is there a way to change the default configuration for the database in a ddev project and save the changes into the project repository?
I mean change the database name, the database usernames and passwords. I see entries for the type of database in config.yaml, but I want to use a database name other than "db". Is this possible?

DDEV uses db by default, but you can add more databases manually and use them instead of db.
More info about DDEV database management.
Example for MariaDB/MySQL, go to the mysql CLI:
ddev mysql -uroot -proot

Create database and user:
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS some_new_database;
CREATE USER 'username'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON some_new_database.* TO 'username'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;

The above can be automated using hooks.
And don't forget to disable settings management, so DDEV won't write default db to your env (if you use framework):
ddev config --disable-settings-management


It may be easier to use ddev import-db to create a new database instead of giving the full creation logic, as explained in the FAQ, https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/stable/users/usage/faq/#can-i-use-additional-databases-with-ddev
